# How to resolve path to migrations folder after webpack bundling

Tags: typescript, webpack, sequelize.js, umzug

I need to pass to Umzug config a path to migrations folder but it is being compressed by webpack is it possible to do?

I've tried to bundle each migrations file separately but Umzug saying that it cannot find method `up()`.

```
    let umzug = new Umzug({
      storage: 'sequelize',

      storageOptions: {
        sequelize: sequelize
      },

      migrations: {
        params: [
          sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
          Sequelize
        ],
        path: './../db/migrations/*')
      }
    })
```

When I try to run them manually just compiled from the webpack it is saying that no method `up()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be a little late to the party since you asked this 7 months ago but I just encountered the same problem so figured I'd post my solution.

I solved this by creating an entrypoint in Webpack for each migration. I used `glob` to fetch the files dynamically then appended them to the entrypoint parameter, using the filename as the entrypoint name.

Then in the `output.filename` function, I check for any entrypoints from my previous list. These entrypoint files are then created within a `migrations` directory to keep them cleanly placed out of the way of the rest of my entrypoint files so that your migrator doesn't try to iterate over them as well.

### webpack.config.js

```
const migrationFiles = glob.sync('./src/migrations/*');
const migrationEntries = migrationFiles.reduce((acc, migrationFile) => {
    const entryName = migrationFile.substring(
        migrationFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
        migrationFile.lastIndexOf('.')
    );
    acc[entryName] = migrationFile;
    return acc;
}, {});

modules.exports {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.ts',
        ...migrationEntries,
    },

    ...

    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        filename: chunkData => {
            if (Object.keys(migrationEntries).includes(chunkData.chunk.id)) {
                return `migrations/${chunkData.chunk.id}.js`;
            }

            return '[name].js';
        },
    },
}
```

Now all of your migrations should be accessible directly as a `.js` file in your `/dist/migrations` directory.

Now for loading Umzug, you can just specify the migration directory path

```
let umzug = new Umzug({
    storage: 'sequelize',

    storageOptions: {
        sequelize: sequelize
    },

    migrations: {
        params: [
            sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
            Sequelize
        ],
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'migrations')
    }
})
```

I'm sure there's a better solution out there, but this one took me longer than I'd like to admit and solves all of my problems, so that's where I ended my search. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Comment: Awesome! You should use `chunkData.chunk.name` instead of `chunkData.chunk.id` in newer webpack versions. ;)